# Replace NULL in my Table with <SOME VALUE> in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

Upon searching ways to replace NULL values in my table with 0 on Stack Overflow, it appears that many threads I've found point to using the COALESCE function. E.g. [postgresql return 0 if returned value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007009/postgresql-return-0-if-returned-value-is-null)

I understand that the COALESCE function "replaces" null values for your specific query; however, the table itself remains untouched. That is, if you queried the table again in a separate query without COALESCE, null values would still exist.

**My question is, is there a way for me to replace NULL values permanently in my table with a specified value (like 0) so I don't have to COALESCE in every query? And as an extension to my question, is it considered bad practice to modify the original table instead of doing manipulations in queries?**

Comment: YOu can add a "Not Null" constraint on that column of table. That would restrict any null in future to be inserted

Comment: Oh, I'm copying the data into the table from a CSV into my table to begin with so NOT NULL didn't work for me (I believe it's because I'm copying in after defining the table? Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: in this case COALESCE is a good option. otherwise you can add a trigger on the insert of the table and replace any Null value from there, regardless from which query that insert is coming from

Comment: Is it many columns that have the null values?

Comment: Around 5 columns have NULL values scattered within them? I just thought that it would be a lot cleaner if I just removed them initially to avoid COALESCING too many times later in queries but tbh I'm a newbie at SQL so not sure about best practices etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just do an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = 0 WHERE col1 IS NULL;
```

This should effectively update all matching records on your table

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! this definitely works; however, I'm not sure `value = NULL` is valid syntax. Should it not be `value IS NULL` instead?

Comment: @phao5814 it should be `IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I understand you got the answer but you can also use in your further query `nvl` function. You can replace at the runtime the NULL values with 0 just to be sure your query is working as expected.

```
SELECT 
        id
       ,nvl(col1, 0)
FROM
       ...
```

It's not updating in the table but you are sure that all NULL values are displayed as 0 like you want. Maybe you forget to update.

Comment: `nvl` is available on Oracle, not Postgres, which uses `coalesce`.