# how to SET value to 0 IF dta is not found in query POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

i have table like this

```
id | name | planned_amount | actual | avail

1   ABC     100                123    100
2   DEF     200                345    200
3   uytuyn  9000               311    300
4   oiui    890                200    200
```

above data output from query like this:

```
select a.name, 
       e.planned_amount, 
       dd.sum as actual, 
       e.planned_amount - dd.sum as avail 
from crossovered_budget_lines as e, 
     account_analytic_account as a, 
     (select analytic_account_id, sum(debit+credit)  
      from account_move_line 
      where date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-05-01' 
      group by analytic_account_id) as dd 
where e.analytic_account_id = a.id 
  and dd.analytic_account_id = .id
 limit 5
```

when range **data** from table **account_move_line** is null ( no output data ), i want to output like this, column **actual** give **0** value :

```
 id | name | planned_amount | actual | avail
    
    1   ABC     100                0    100
    2   DEF     200                0    200
    3   uytuyn  9000               0    300
    4   oiui    890                0    200
```

how to query to produce the output above ? iam stuck , thanks

Comment: Dupe:  [postgresql return 0 if returned value is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007009/postgresql-return-0-if-returned-value-is-null)

Comment: how to implement from my query ?

Comment: As the answer says, use [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).  Basically `select ... dd.sum ...` becomes `select coalesce(dd.sum, 0) ...`

Comment: give me example from my query

Comment: You are looking for an outer join - but to use it, you have to ditch the ancient implicit join conditions in the WHERE clause and switch to the "modern" (nearly 30 years old) explicit `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` operators